# Simple c# to put and get a single log line in a AWS bucket

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, logging

So, we have a bucket that's been created and has files in it, but we need to log whenever files are added, removed, or viewed.

I'm looking for something simple, such as:

```
        using (s3Client = new AmazonS3Client("accessKeyId", "secretAccessKey", "sessionToken", bucketRegion)) {
// log an entry here--"New file added! Filename: 'foo.gif'"
// get all log entries in the past day }
```

Is this doable or is that a lot of other work surrounding it? I've success fully used GetBucketLoggingRequest against this bucket, but it's just returning what looks to be an encoded string and not what I'd expect.

I've read that Console.Write and Writeline automatically log and that's fine for our sample console app but we won't be using those in our web api.

Hopefully I'm just missing something simple, most of the examples I can find are Java/E2 which don't do me much good. Thanks!

Comment: GetBucketLoggingRequest only returns the applied logging permissions on the bucket. Can you explain more about logging? Are you trying to log to a file in S3? Or a log file produced by your process?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you need to publish S3 bucket notifications to SQS and then receive these notifications in your applications, as described [here](https://alestic.com/2014/12/s3-bucket-notification-to-sqssns-on-object-creation/) or [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ways-to-add-notification-config-to-bucket.html)